# do not fire onclick default function if checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

If someone clicks the "Buy now" button, without ticking the checkbox, the button shouldnt fire the default function (in this example no alert with "hello"), but it should mark the checkbox with a red border. But when the box is checked, it should fire the default function (in this case alert with "hello).

I am struggling to disable the default function without disabling the button. Also out of some reason its not creating the red border. How can I solve this?

```js
$("#upsellyes").click(function() {
  alert('hello');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")) {
    $("#upsellyes").click(function() {
      $("#terms-required").css('border', '1px solid red;');
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terms-required" style="font-size: 11px;margin: 10px 0 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" style="position: absolute;">
  <label for="terms" class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block!important;font-weight:normal!important;margin-left: 25px;">Ich habe die <a href="" target="_blank">Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a> gelesen und akzeptiert. <span class="required">*</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" id="upsellyes">Buy now</a>
<p>or</p>
<a href="#"><br />No thanks </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic needs to be invereted so that you check the state of the checkbox *within* the click handler, not only when the page loads. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#upsellyes").click(function(e) {
    if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#terms-required").addClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $("#terms-required").removeClass('invalid');
      console.log('box has been checked...');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#terms-required {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#terms {
  position: absolute;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="terms-required">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
  <label for="terms" class="checkbox">
    Ich habe die <a href="" target="_blank">Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a> gelesen und akzeptiert. 
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
</div><br />

<a href="#" id="upsellyes">Buy now</a>
<p>or</p>
<a href="#">No thanks </a>
```

Also note that you shouldn't be using inline styling in your HTML. I extracted those style rule to a stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$("#upsellyes").click(function() {
  if ($("#terms").is(":checked")) {
    alert('hello');
  } else {
    $("#terms-required").css('border', '1px solid red');
  }
});

$("#terms").click(function() {
  $("#terms-required").css('border', $(this).is(":checked") ? 'none' : '1px solid red');
});
```

It will check if the checkbox is checked and apply / remove the border depending on it.

**Demo**

```js
$("#upsellyes").click(function() {
  if ($("#terms").is(":checked")) {
    alert('hello');
  } else {
    $("#terms-required").css('border', '1px solid red');
  }
});

$("#terms").click(function() {
  $("#terms-required").css('border', $(this).is(":checked") ? 'none' : '1px solid red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terms-required" style="font-size: 11px;margin: 10px 0 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" style="position: absolute;">
  <label for="terms" class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block!important;font-weight:normal!important;margin-left: 25px;">Ich habe die <a href="" target="_blank">Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a> gelesen und akzeptiert. <span class="required">*</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" id="upsellyes">Buy now</a>
<p>or</p>
<a href="#"><br />No thanks </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can also use `return false;` in your click handler after checking checked state.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#upsellyes").click(function(e) {
    if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")) {
      $("#terms-required").addClass('invalid');
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#terms-required").removeClass('invalid');

    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly changed your snippet. Hope it will be useful.

```js
function termsChecked() {
    return $("#terms").is(":checked");
}

$("#upsellyes").click(function() {
  if (termsChecked()) {
    alert('hello');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#upsellyes").click(function() {
    if (!termsChecked()) {
      $("#terms-required").css('border', '3px solid red');
    }
    else {
      $("#terms-required").css('border', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terms-required" style="font-size: 11px;margin: 10px 0 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" style="position: absolute;">
  <label for="terms" class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block!important;font-weight:normal!important;margin-left: 25px;">Ich habe die <a href="" target="_blank">Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a> gelesen und akzeptiert. <span class="required">*</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" id="upsellyes">Buy now</a>
<p>or</p>
<a href="#"><br />No thanks </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hope this work :)

```
$("#upsellyes").click(function(){
  if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")) {
        $("#terms-required").css('border', 'border: 1px solid red;');
            }
  else{
        alert('hello');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an if block before the click function.
Since you have 2 of the same click functions, both would fire. Therefore you would always receive the hello alert no matter if the box is ticked or not.

Just change the click function in general

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upsellyes").click(function() {
      if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")) {
        alert("hello");
      else{
        $("#terms-required").css("border", "1px solid red");
      }
    });
  }
})
```